# How can I increase the y of the spawned object (Instantiate)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

How can I make the prefab2 Instanitiate at higher y than prefab1. They are spawned randomly from the same position. The code:

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
    {

        what = Random.Range(1, 3);
        Debug.Log(what);
        switch (what)
        {
            case 1:
                Instantiate(prefab1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 2:
                Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position.y, Quaternion.identity);
                break;

        }
        nextSpawn = Time.time + SpawnRate;
    }
}
```

}

Sorry, I know the sollution is probably very simple, but I just can't find it.

Comment: Take a look at how `Vector3` works: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your *Instatiate* method call. In the way you are using it, the second parameter needs to be of type `Vector3` and `transform.position.y` is of type `float`. Here is some example code that I believe you will find useful.

```
float spawnRate = 5f;
float spawnTime;

//how high you would like your new object to spawn above transform.position
float yValueDifference = 5f;

void Update () 
{

    if (Time.time - spawnTime > spawnRate) 
    {
        //pick a random number from 0-1
        int type = Random.Range(0, 2);

        Vector3 position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        if (type == 1)
            position.y += yValueDifference;

        //if type is 0, use prefab1, if type is 1, use prefab2
        GameObject prefab = type == 0 ? prefab1 : prefab2;
        Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);

        //reset the timer
        spawnTime = Time.time;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be to create a float (e.g. `public float prefab2YOffset = 1f;`) and then when you instantiate prefab2, you can do something like `Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position + Vector3.up * prefab2YOffset, Quaternion.identity);`. Vector3.up is shorthand for writing Vector3(0, 1, 0), and we're multiplying that vector by your desired offset on the y axis (prefab2YOffset), and adding it to the original position you would instantiate prefab2 at.
I would also recommend reading the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) on how Vector3's work.

Comment: I used this before, but it didn't work. I simply needed to define the x as transform.position.x couldn't only use Vector3.up. Anyways thank you for your effort to anwser my question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
    {

        what = Random.Range(1, 3);
        Debug.Log(what);
        switch (what)
        {
            case 1:
                Instantiate(prefab1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                break;
            case 2:
                Vector3 tp = new Vector3(transform.position.x, -2, 0);
                Instantiate(prefab2, tp, Quaternion.identity);
                break;

        }
        nextSpawn = Time.time + SpawnRate;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a solution, thanks for help everyone. I was just impatient!